# sendmail time option

Tags: linux, unix, shell, sendmail

is there any option to sendmail linux command on particular time .

I want make or sending email on particular time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a `cron` job to execute `sendmail` at any particular time.

Comment: that i can do .. is there any option ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`at`](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?at) command to execute the command once at a later time.  One advantage of `at` over `cron` is that `at` uses your environment instead of `cron` which uses a very basic environment.

Comment: You can set any environment you want for a cron job.

Comment: Yes, but you have to explicitly set it.  You get your current environment by default with `at`